# Jquery tabs to display one height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery tabs to display different content.

my functions looks like this:

```
$(function() {

      $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    });
```

I have tried to make all the tabs the same height by doing it like this:

```
var heightStyle = $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle" );

// Setter
$( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle", "fill" );
```

But this does not seem to work.

Is there another way to set the height to the highest tab?

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `selector`, in the above code you are using `$("#tabs").tabs();` accessing by `id`, in below code you are using `$(".tabs")` accessing by `class`.

Comment: I am not a smart man :/ Thank you for the eyes on deck, been up for a bit too long

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery and change class as per your wish

```
$(function(){
    jQuery.fn.equalHeight = function () {
        var tallest = 0;
        this.each(function() {
            tallest = ($(this).height() > tallest)? $(this).height() : tallest;
        });
        return this.height(tallest);    
    }

    //Now you can call equalHeight
    $(".equaltab").equalHeight();
});
```

Comment: you need to add class equaltab to all tabs, then only it will work.